# LSM9DS0's Accelerometer not reading correctly

Tags: i2c, accelerometer, logic-level, error

I have a LSM9DS0 Gyroscope/Accelerometer/Magnetometer breakout board. I am using an Arduino Uno which operates on 5V. The LSM9DS0 is communicating to the Uno using I2C through a Logic Level Converter. The Uno and the LSM9DS0 are connected in parallel to my power supply. The Accelerometer function worked fine the first few times, but when I turn the power supply off and then back on to reboot everything, the Accelerometer seems to fail. Instead of actually getting a accurate number, I receive -1.50; Even if I move the board, I still get that number.

I have researched this and have found nothing. The only thing that fixes this seems to be unplugging the LSM9DS0 and then plugging it back in. I am truly puzzled by this. 
Do you have any suggestions or solutions to this problem?

Comment: You can add your own answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trouble shooting, I am certain that I have found the reason for this. I am posting this in-case anyone else has this issue. When resetting (Cutting power and returning power) the LSM9DS0 may retain some information since the power has been cut during communications w/ the arduino. This causes the board to read -1.50. Resetting again would not fix this issue. My USB was connected to the board the whole time. The USB supplies the board with a small amount of current (I am using a stand alone arduino, so the power is coming through the RX and TX pins) and thus does not allow for a true reset. If the USB cable is removed and then the board is reset, all issues will be solved.